# How to install cocos-2d templates in Xcode 6.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to create new cocos 2d project, for that i need to have cocos2d template in xcode 6.3. What i did I downloaded lattest cocos2D 3.4. In that there is no install-templates.sh/install.sh file in order to install template. Help me get rid off it?

Is it possible to create new project without using SpriteBuilder?.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "you can't use templates in Cocos2d v3", however for v4, they are considering their re-introduction or the use of something similar.

The only supported method of starting a new project is to create it via SpriteBuilder, however you are not required to use SpriteBuilder to develop the game once it's been created.  See [this post](http://forum.cocos2d-objc.org/t/installing-cocos2d-spritebuilder/15916) from the Cocos2d forum.

SpriteBuilder can be downloaded from the Mac App Store.